# Activate an imageslider based on the size of the device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My code at the moment is very repetitive and very long, which to me is not clean code.

When on a big device:

```
<div class="hidden-xs">
    <ul class="ul-class-name">
        <li><img src="" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And when you move to a small screen/device I implement a jQuery image slider which uses JavaScript to initiate:

```
<div class="visible-xs">
    <ul class="imageslider">
        <li><img src="" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>


$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('.imageslider').bxSlider({

    });
```

The content inside the `<ul>`'s is exactly the same, so with several images the code is very long.

How can I make the imageslider activate ONLY for mobile/xs devices using just one line of code to combine them both like so `<ul class="ul-class-name imageslider">`? I want to merge the 2 together in order to save on A LOT of code.

Comment: Do you want that slider to be visible on large/normal screens thou?

Comment: @Rami.Shareef No, on large screens I don't want an image slider used.

Answer (score 0):

Hve this into your css code:

```
@media screen and (min-width:761px){
     .imageslider{ visibility:hidden; 
}

@media screen and (max-width:760px){
      .imageslider{ visibility:hidden;
}

@media screen and (max-width:480px){
     .imageslider{ visibility:visible;
}

@media screen and (max-width:360px){
        .imageslider{ visibility:visible;
    }
```

Yes this is right method you can use n-number of classes by adding space;

Comment: This seems to put my images into an imageslider even when the screen is fully maximized, I only want to activate imageslider when the screen is small

Comment: If I add this to my code then surely this will hide my entire set of images on a large screen? I still want to display my images on a large screen, just not using the imageslider.

Comment: i have just applied Visibility to your imageslider class that means if your screen is smaall then it will be visible! make other div for larger screen and give visibility hidden when screen size is small!

Comment: I want to be able to put them together in just 1 div. At the moment my code is very long and inefficient, I want to have the images in just 1 div where I can activate the imageslider when screen size is small

Answer (score 0):

You can use `media query` to show the slider when it is displayed on mobile screen sized

the `@media only screen and (min-width:50px) and (max-width:500px)` will run only when a screen's width is between `50` and `500` px

You may combine them into one container, and then switch visibility between different screen sizes

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="ul-class-name">
        <li><img src="" /></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="imageslider">
        <li><img src="" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.imageslider {
            display: none;
        }
    @media only screen and (min-width:50px) and (max-width:500px) {
        .imageslider {
            display: block;
        }
        .ul-class-name{
            display:none;
                }
    }
```

Comment: I have already done this using my original code, using bootstrap's `hidden-xs` and `visible-xs` but this requires me to have TWO identical div's with the only difference being that one is an imageslider which "replaces" the other div when the screen is small.

Comment: What the other div would have inside when it is in a normal screen size?

Comment: You may combine them into one container, and then switch visibility between different screen sizes

Comment: Both of the div's at the moment have exactly the same code, a set of 3 images. I don't want to use two almost identical div's as it's inefficient and leaves excess code. So I want to have 1 div, where the images are placed into an imageslider only if the screen size is small